# Can not convert to Poco::UTF16String

Tags: json, poco, poco-libraries

Code sniff is below:

```
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr JsonObject = jsonObject->getObject("Policy");
std::ostringstream stream;
JsonObject->stringify(stream);
```

In the above line getting a poco exception :

"**Err: Can not convert to Poco::UTF16String**"

Comment: I think you need to provide more information.  What version of Poco?  Have you tried to debug this exception and inspect the callstack?

Comment: There are template specializations of Dynamic::VarHolderImpl for many types but only Int8, Int16, std::string, and UTF16String have convert functions to UTF16String.  See `void convert(Poco::UTF16String& val) const`

Comment: I am using a poco version 1.11.1, there my code is getting the issue. In the Previous release 1.10.1, the same code is working fine without any exception. I took a diff between the two releases and found that a number of changes are there in the "poco/dynamic/var.h, varholder.h , pair.h and struct.h"